# Find parameter in trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find the values of $a$ so that the equation has real solution.

$$2a \sin^2 x - 2 \sin x \cos x = a - \sqrt{3}$$

I tried rewriting  $2 \sin x \cos x$ as $\sin 2x$, also write $\sin^2 x = \frac{1- \cos 2x}{2}$ but havent't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Divide both sides by either $\cos^2x$ and write $\dfrac1{\cos^2x}=1+\tan^2x$ in the right hand side to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$

Now for real solution, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

We can divide by $\sin^2x$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

you must use that $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a 4th degree equation?

Comment: This is good hint actually.

Answer (score 1):

$$2a \sin^2 x - 2 \sin x \cos x = a - \sqrt{3}$$

$$2a \sin^2 x -a -2\sin x \cos x=-\sqrt3$$

$$-a(1-2\sin^2 x) -(\sin 2x)=-\sqrt 3$$

$$a\cos 2x + \sin 2x =\sqrt 3$$

$$a\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2 x} +\dfrac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}=\sqrt 3$$

$$\dfrac{a-a\tan^2 x +2\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}=\sqrt3$$

$$a\tan^2 x +\sqrt 3 \tan^2 x-2\tan x+\sqrt 3 -a=0$$

$$(a+\sqrt 3) \tan^2 x -2\tan x+(\sqrt 3-a)=0$$

$$\tan x=\dfrac{2±\sqrt{4-4(a+\sqrt 3)(a-\sqrt 3)}}{2(a+\sqrt 3)}$$

$$\tan x=\dfrac{1±\sqrt{1-1(a^2-3)}}{(a+\sqrt 3)}$$

If you need you can further simplify to get answer as required. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Break equation and then convert all into 2x
   2aSin²x - 2SinxConx = a - √3

aSin²x + a(1 - Cos²x) - Sin2x = a - √3

aSin²x - aCos²x - c = -√3

aCos2x = √3 - Sin2x

2. Squaring:

a²Cos²2x = 3 + Sin²2x - 2√3Sin2x

a²(1 - Sin²2x) = 3 + Sin²2x - 2√3Sin2x

Now it is a quadratic equation in Sin2x from which you can determine a 
condition on a

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Take a minute to look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typesetting your answer to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks DMcMor! I will certainly make sure to use MathJax next time!